# What does "razor-cheekboned wisdom" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

". Three times I've watched the first half of season one of Breaking Bad, three times I've given up on the coughing, the chemicals, the camper van, the crack and the corpses. In the meantime, I cackle on about Westeros, about Cersai Lannister and her wonky, regal, razor-cheekboned wisdom; Cersai, perched in her palace room in King's Landing, goblet of plonk in hand, slurring sadly for her boyfriend Jamie. He's also her brother, but, gosh he's handsome and hard as nails, so we overlook the vomitous aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance of the figure of speech traditional rhetoric called [hypallage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage): the transfer of an 'epithet' from one entity to a different but related entity.

In this case, *razor-cheekboned*, although it appears to modify *wisdom*, is in fact understood to modify the possessor of that wisdom, Cersei Lanister. The character is played by an actor with markedly high cheekbones, which the author characterizes as 'sharp' as a razor.

Comment: The actress in question does not have  high cheekbones at all. You can google her picture and see. So, even if it characterizes her, you have not explained the meaning at all, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Lambie Well, cheekbones seem to be in the eye of the beholder. I'm not alone in seeing them as high, and you're not alone in seeing tehm as unremarkable: just google "Lena Headey cheekbones" and see the debate unfold (ignoring irrelevant references to Tyrion's remark in the original novels) !

Comment: In Game of Thrones, the actress cannot be said  to have high cheekbones. She just doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

razor-cheekboned is a poetic construction.

razor here stands for a cutting instrument, as in: her cutting sarcasm, a usual phrase. Or "cutting" wisdom in this case. Meaning: she delivers her words of wisdom with a sharp tone. Her wisdom is cutting, sharp or even mean.

The character Cersei Lannister in Game of Thrones is very sarcastic.

Secondly, cheekbones are associated with a person's beauty. For women, high cheekbones are a sign of beauty. She doesn't actually have  high cheekbones, but cheekbones are still associated with beauty. In short, "cheekbones" refer to her face or look.

So, basically, the author is saying that Cersei delivers her words of wisdom with a look on her face that resembles a cutting instrument.